# Symfony: How to inject AuthorizationChecker in phpunit Test

Tags: phpunit, symfony5.4

A colleage changed the code of my service to use the isGranted method of of the AuthorizationCheckerInterface to check the rights. Like this:

```
$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(Roles::ROLE_PERSON_VIEW);
```

Regretfully, he didn't adapt my phpunit tests so I am left with changing my tests so they pass again.

The service I am testing is created like this in my test:

```
protected function getService(string $id): ?object
{
    $kernel = static::createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();

    return $kernel
        ->getContainer()
        ->get($id);
}

    /** @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker */
    $authorizationChecker = $this->getService('AuthorizationChecker');

    $this->manager = new Manager(
        $entityManager,
        $fooService,
        $baaService,
        $authorizationChecker
    );
```

Which results in the error:

```
ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "AuthorizationChecker"
```

I first tried mocking the service, but without defining the result I got "null" and defining the result makes it quite useless for my tests, because I mock the user right already and want to test if they play together correctly with the rest of my code, so it is a kind of functional test, rather than a unit test.

If I create the AuthorizationChecker manually I have the same problem with the TokenStorageInterface and the AccessDecisionManagerInterface.

What is the best way to test my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was creating a variation of mocks with closures. I really hoped I could avoid that. So it was a kind of middle way between really using the AuthorizationChecker and writing it again as a mock. However if anyone has a more satisfying solution that would be great.

My problem is that with every method I test I check different rights/roles, so just setting the mock to give back `true` or `false`isn't enough. What I have here is that I can set it up for two different Symfony roles in one go and there for I have 4 variations. 'FACH' and 'PERSON' are substrings of my role names. The whole role name would be something like PRESON_CREATE

This is what I did:

```php
    private function mockAuthorizationChecker(string $role, bool $person = false, bool $fach = false)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $this->createMock(AuthorizationCheckerInterface::class);
        if ($person && $fach) {
            $this->authorizationChecker
                ->method('isGranted')
                ->willReturnCallback(
                    function ($role) {
                        $isGranted = false;
                        if (strpos($role, 'FACH')) {
                            $isGranted = true;
                        }
                        if (strpos($role, 'PERSON')) {
                            $isGranted = true;
                        }

                        return $isGranted;
                    }
                );
        }

        if ($person && !$fach) {
            $this->authorizationChecker
                ->method('isGranted')
                ->willReturnCallback(
                    function ($role) {
                        $isGranted = false;
                        if (strpos($role, 'FACH')) {
                            $isGranted = false;
                        }
                        if (strpos($role, 'PERSON')) {
                            $isGranted = true;
                        }

                        return $isGranted;
                    }
                );
        }

        if (!$person && $fach) {
            $this->authorizationChecker
                ->method('isGranted')
                ->willReturnCallback(
                    function ($role) {
                        $isGranted = false;
                        if (strpos($role, 'FACH')) {
                            $isGranted = true;
                        }
                        if (strpos($role, 'PERSON')) {
                            $isGranted = false;
                        }

                        return $isGranted;
                    }
                );
        }

        if (!$person && !$fach) {
            $this->authorizationChecker
                ->method('isGranted')
                ->willReturnCallback(
                    function ($role) {
                        $isGranted = false;
                        if (strpos($role, 'FACH')) {
                            $isGranted = false;
                        }
                        if (strpos($role, 'PERSON')) {
                            $isGranted = false;
                        }

                        return $isGranted;
                    }
                );
        }
    }
```